# I get this error --> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, opencv, keras

I get this error many times.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                        
  File "E:\AI and ML-pr\day14\test.py", line 38, in <module>
  result = loaded_model.predict(test_image)
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

I want to find out the diseases of the leaves of the plant.

my code::

```
# importing libraries
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.models import model_from_json
import os
import cv2

#loading tha model

json_file=open('modell.json','r')
loaded_model_json=json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model=model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

# load weights into new model
loaded_model = loaded_model.load_weights("modell.h5")
print("Loaded model succesfully**")

label = ['Apple___Apple_scab','Apple___Black_rot','Apple___Cedar_apple_rust','Apple___healthy',     
'Blueberry___healthy','Cherry_(including_sour)___healthy','Cherry_(including_sour)___Powdery_mildew','Corn_(maize)___Cercospora_leaf_spot Gray_leaf_spot','Corn_(maize)___Common_rust_', 'Corn_(maize)___healthy','Corn_(maize)___Northern_Leaf_Blight','Grape___Black_rot','Grape___Esca_(Black_Measles)','Grape___healthy','Grape___Leaf_blight_(Isariopsis_Leaf_Spot)','Orange___Haunglongbing_(Citrus_greening)','Peach___Bacterial_spot','Peach___healthy','Pepper,_bell___Bacterial_spot','Pepper,_bell___healthy','Potato___Early_blight','Potato___healthy','Potato___Late_blight','Raspberry___healthy','Soybean___healthy','Squash___Powdery_mildew','Strawberry___healthy','Strawberry___Leaf_scorch','Tomato___Bacterial_spot','Tomato___Early_blight','Tomato___healthy','Tomato___Late_blight','Tomato___Leaf_Mold','Tomato___Septoria_leaf_spot','Tomato___Spider_mites Two-spotted_spider_mite','Tomato___Target_Spot','Tomato___Tomato_mosaic_virus','Tomato___Tomato_Yellow_Leaf_Curl_Virus']

path="E:\AI and ML-pr\day14\images_for_test\AppleCedarRust1.jpg"
test_image=image.load_img(path,target_size=(128,128))
#print(test_image)
test_image=image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image=np.expand_dims(test_image,axis=1)
result = loaded_model.predict(test_image)
print(result)
fresult=np.max(result)
label2=label[result.argmax()]
print(label2)
```

**please solve my problem**

Comment: Did you debug? Try `if loaded_model: print("Loaded model succesfully**") else: print("Not loaded")`

Comment: The path to your `h5` file - are you sure it is the correct one?

Comment: Don't try use a `predict` method on a variable with value `None`!  You could go the next step and figure out why `loaded_model` is `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be the line:
`loaded_model = loaded_model.load_weights("modell.h5")`

From the [documentation for load_weights()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#load_weights):

> When loading a weight file in TensorFlow format, returns the same status object as
> tf.train.Checkpoint.restore. When graph building, restore ops are run automatically
> as soon as the network is built (on first call for user-defined classes inheriting
> from Model, immediately if it is already built).

> When loading weights in HDF5 format, returns None.

So it looks like changing the line to be just:
`loaded_model.load_weights("modell.h5")`
would resolve your issue.